# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in (word-press plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I just installed a plugin to my word-press site and now I'm getting this message:

Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home2/royaldlx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-hotel-booking-lite/includes/admin/manage-cpt-pages/booking-manage-cpt-page.php on line 194

What had happened? is there any way to fix it? Thank you in advance. 
Below the code:

```
 if ( !empty( $customer->getEmail() ) ) {
                                $customerInfo .= '<br />'
                                    . '<a href="mailto:' . esc_attr( $customer->getEmail() ) . '">'
                                        . esc_html( $customer->getEmail() )
                                    . '</a>';
                            }
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Ok code added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two conflicts. Either you didnt install you wordpress right or your plugin is conflicted, try to change plugin or re-install wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but question: I can reinstall word-press by c-panel right? and is there any risk to lose all my website?

Comment: There probably is, so you should make sure that you backup everything properly first.

Comment: Simply deleting the specific plugin folder via FTP most likely should be able to get your site running again already though.

Comment: No, there is no risk to loose your site simple, extract your database, and download all files. then do it. or you can remove your plugin as well